# How to get the total sales generated by a Shopify store using REST API

Tags: php, rest, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

We are developing a Shopify app.

**What is the best way to get the total sales generated by a Shopify store over a period using REST API?**

So far, we have tried [Order REST API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/order). But as we have to paginate through 250 orders per page and calculate the total sales for each page of orders, it is taking too long than expected to get the total sales.

Is there any single API call or any other effective way to get the total sales?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't a single api call you can do. If it's an operation you need to do once in a while you can use the graphql bulk api https://shopify.dev/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries

Comment: Shopify has a reporting language for this kind of purpose. You can try that. Also, when you use phrases like "it takes too long", your credibility in understanding the domain gets tarnished. Computers do your bidding. Accept it. This is not firefighters responding to a burning building. It's an App.